# Redirecting with Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, redirect

I'm trying to make a login feature on a practice site and I want to redirect to another url when the login is successful.
I use nodejs, express and mongoDB.
When I redirect to the new url it will take one parameter that is the _id of the document in mongoDB.

I get an url that looks right with the right _id `/users/1234567abc` but I'm on the wrong one because it does not respond to my `console.log` and it tells me "cannot get url ...".

Any ideas?

```html
/*in app.js*/
app.use('/users/:id', users);

...

/*in routes/users.js*/
router.get('/:id');

...

/*The code in the function*/

connected to mongo....

if(pass1 === pass2){
  var redirectUrl = "/users/" + _id.fromDB;
  res.redirect(redirectUrl);
}...
```

Comment: Remove your :id from users.js file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when I made a `/users` and then a `/users/:id` route it worked... If anyone knows why then please let me know.